# Create multiple step in auto hot key

Tags: autohotkey

I am new in autohotkey (AHK). I need to create some manual steps by automatically like when i upload a CSV the automation script will run after upload CSV will read and get account number from CSV and search this user in database and get all data from database also search folder of that user and this will print all data in one PDF and store new PDF save on one location.

```
Here is the process : 

1 : Upload one CSV with multiple users like account #0001,#0002,#0003 etc 
2 : After upload CSV automation script will run and start search user by account number one by one and get all record from folder and print on the PDF 
3 : create pdf for every user and store in my set location like user_0001.pdf , user_0002.pdf etc....
```

I have user below code and read CSV but for next step i am stuck. let me know.

```
Loop, read, path/csv_read.csv
{
    LineNumber = %A_Index%
    Loop, parse, A_LoopReadLine, CSV
    {

    field%a_index%=%A_LoopField%
;listvars
;        MsgBox, 4, , Field %LineNumber%-%A_Index% is:`n%A_LoopField%`n`nContinue?
;        IfMsgBox, No
;            return
    }
   msgbox %field1% %field2% %field3% %field4% %field5% %field6%
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what has this to do with PHP?

Comment: @Twinfriends accidentally i was addedd

Comment: No problem, happens. Good luck with your question.

Comment: "This script is possible by AHK." Im not seeing a way for AHK to natively create PDF's. Are you aware of a way this can be done or are you just assuming that? @PriteshMahajan

Comment: I want to create this type of script but i am unable to find any solution yet.

Comment: Okay I would edit your verbiage on this question since you dont really know if it is possible yet.

Comment: sure, you can no problem

Comment: What do you want, again? You've commented out stuff. Why do you need to save the outer loop index (as LineNumber)?  The way you have it, it seems to me, reading each new line in csv_read.csv will over-write the six parsed field#s of the inner loop.  Does your CSV file have 6 account number items in each line, or is it one account per line, and that's in the sixth field?